# How to detect Rails environment inside whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, rake, whenever

This question will probably only make sense if you know about the **[whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)** gem for creating **cron** jobs.

For my app, I want to use `whenever` in all the environments, including *testing* and *development*.
My `schedule.rb` looks like this:

```
set :output, {
    :error    => "#{path}/log/error.log",
    :standard => "#{path}/log/cron.log"
}

set :environment, Rails.env.to_sym
every 5.minutes do
  rake 'db:activity:synchronize'
end
```

but it fails on `Rails.env.to_sym` (*and the same stands for* `RAILS_ENV`):

```
/home/marius/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@uxolo/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:21:in `eval': uninitialized constant Whenever::JobList::Rails (NameError)
    from /home/marius/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@uxolo/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:21:in `eval'
    from /home/marius/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@uxolo/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:21:in `initialize'
    from /home/marius/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@uxolo/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever.rb:15:in `new'
    from /home/marius/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@uxolo/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever.rb:15:in `cron'
    from /home/marius/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@uxolo/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:41:in `run'
    from /home/marius/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@uxolo/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:8:in `execute'
    from /home/marius/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@uxolo/gems/whenever-0.6.8/bin/whenever:38:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/marius/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@uxolo/bin/whenever:19:in `load'
    from /home/marius/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@uxolo/bin/whenever:19:in `<main>'
```

So, my question basically boils down to:

1. How do I access the current environment, *or*
2. What should I do to use `whenever` in all the environments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message suggests that Rails isn't defined. i.e the framework isn't loaded when you're asking the question what environment is rails running with.

In fact from looking at the code for Whenever it looks like rails isn't a requirement for it (i.e. You can install and run Whenever without rails even being installed on your system). Hence there's no way for Whenever to look at your rails environment (as far as i can tell)

Answer (score 29):

At least in newer version of whenever it is possible to access the environment with `@environment`. For example if you want whenever to only generate cron entries for some jobs in production:

```
case @environment
when 'production'
  every 1.day, :at => '0:00 am' do
    rake "some:task"
  end 
end
```

Comment: In my case, this told me `production` instead of `development`, whereas the solutions of @JCoster22 worked fine (development while in development, and production on production)

Comment: Hmm the `@environment` variable is "production" even in development env? sounds bad

Comment: @MattiasWadman: yes, the environment is production by default. I use `bundle exec whenever --set "environment=development"` to override this.

Answer (score 9):

As [recommended by the gem author](https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/162), the solution is to [pass in the current environment as a variable](https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/Setting-variables-on-the-fly):

```
$ whenever --set environment=test
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/marius/uxolo && RAILS_ENV=test rake db:activity:synchronize --silent >> /home/marius/uxolo/log/cron.log 2>> /home/marius/uxolo/log/error.log'

$ whenever --set environment=development
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/marius/uxolo && RAILS_ENV=development rake db:activity:synchronize --silent >> /home/marius/uxolo/log/cron.log 2>> /home/marius/uxolo/log/error.log'
```

And Chris Bailey is right: `Whenever` itself doesn't load the Rails environment.

Answer (score 8):

A variation of the first answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978177/whenever-gem-schedule-rb-file-doesnt-recongize-rails-root-variable) worked for me. Add

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment")
```

to the top of `schedule.rb` and you'll be able to call Rails.env to access the current Rails environment.

Note: the above path would be different if your `environment.rb` file isn't in `/app/config`

Answer (score 1):

I took the implementation of `Rails.env` I found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails.html#method-c-env) (by clicking on "source"), and used it to initialize the `::Rails` module at the beginning of the `config/schedule.rb`

```
eval %Q(module ::Rails
  def self.env
    '#{@environment}' || ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"
  end
end
)
```

This creates the `Rails` module, and makes its environment return what you supplied as `--set environment=...` in the `whenever` command line, as the script author suggests.

However, **whenever sets the `@environment` to production by default**, so this large "or" may be not quite useful.

Now the `Rails.env` call in the Whenever script would work.  What was more important in my case, it also worked in other scripts I included into `schedule.rb`, such as the one that loaded `application.yml`.

P.S. The `eval` call is used to access `@environment` available in the scope of the `schedule.rb` script from inside the definition of a module.